# Pyspark how to filter out data in datafram that exists in a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter out data in dataframe that exists in a different tuple list.

For example, my existing_df contains the following data:

```
| one_id |  another_id  | val1 | val2 | val3 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1      |  11          | a1   | b1   | c1   |
| 2      |  12          | a2   | b2   | c2   |
| 3      |  13          | a3   | b3   | c3   |
| 4      |  14          | a4   | b4   | c4   |

list1 = ['1','2']
list2 = ['11','12']
```

The expected result is the following dataframe:

```
| one_id |  another_id  | val1 | val2 | val3 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 3      |  13          | a3   | b3   | c3   |
| 4      |  14          | a4   | b4   | c4   |
```

In my code I am doing the following:

```
keys = some_df.select("one_id", "another_id")\
    .rdd.map(lambda r: (str(r[0]),str(r[1]),)).distinct().collect()
list1, list2 = zip(*keys)


existing_df.filter(
    ~existing_df.one_id.fn.isin(list1) & ~existing_df.another_id.fn.isin(list2)
)
```

and I and getting the following exception:

> ```
> {Py4JJavaError}An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
> : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [oneId1, oneId2]
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:78)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.$anonfun$create$2(literals.scala:164)
>   at scala.util.Failure.getOrElse(Try.scala:222)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:164)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:127)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:110)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(functions.scala)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at py4j.reflection.MethodIn...
> ```

Comment: Why are you using `collect`? Seems like you should just use an `antijoin`. Please post a [mcve] if you want more details. As it's currently written, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost close.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,11,'a1','b1','c1'),(2,12,'a2','b2','c2'),(3,13,'a3','b3','c3'),(4,14,'a4','b4','c4')],['one_id','another_id','val1','val2','val3'])
list1 = ['1','2']
list2 = ['11','12']
```

You can use `NOT isin()` through this syntax  (`isin() == False` or `~isin()`)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.where((col('one_id').isin(list1) == False) & (col('another_id').isin(list2) == False)).show()

#+------+----------+----+----+----+
#|one_id|another_id|val1|val2|val3|
#+------+----------+----+----+----+
#|     3|        13|  a3|  b3|  c3|
#|     4|        14|  a4|  b4|  c4|
#+------+----------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
The exception's root cause was that I used list of tuple types so I also needed to convert list1 and list2 to list of strings, so I have added this:
list1 = [''.join(i) for i in list1]
list2 = [''.join(i) for i in list2]
And now it is doing exactly what I was expected. Thank you for your help.